# IPC Communication : Recieving a C application posted structure in python using POSIX IPC

Tags: python, posix, ipc, structure

We developing a IPC module

where application A (C application uses Mqueue) will POSt a structure data in IPC Queue

Application B (python Based uses POSIX IPC for Python) has to access the queue and fetch the structure data

Since Python has not got direct structure handling capability..How would i receive the posted structure from the Queue

or what is the way to handle this issue..

Comment: Is the issue that you're getting raw bytes in Python, as a string, and want to interpret that string as a C-like structure?  See the [struct](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html) module.

Comment: @ArminRigo: yes struct really helped but i have some clarifications in that will post in other question by monday morning